# variable not defined even after I use require keyword in nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

Hi I am new to Nodejs and I am having a problem when debugging a server example through node debugger.

This is part of `server.js`, the file I'm trying to inspect.

```
// Babel ES6/JSX Compiler
require('babel-register');

var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var compression = require('compression');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var async = require('async');
var colors = require('colors');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

I was debugging this file on the terminal by `node debug server.js` command.
When I tried to inspect the `path` variable above, I've got this.

```
debug> path
{ resolve: [Function],
  normalize: [Function],
  isAbsolute: [Function],
  join: [Function],
  relative: [Function],
  _makeLong: [Function],
  dirname: [Function],
  basename: [Function],
  extname: [Function],
  format: [Function],
  parse: [Function],
  sep: '/',
  delimiter: ':',
  posix: [Circular],
  win32: 
   { resolve: [Function],
     normalize: [Function],
     isAbsolute: [Function],
     join: [Function],
     relative: [Function],
     _makeLong: [Function],
     dirname: [Function],
     basename: [Function],
     extname: [Function],
     format: [Function],
     parse: [Function],
     sep: '\\',
     delimiter: ';' } }
```

However when I tried to inspect `express`, the debugger keeps saying it's not defined. This is same to other variables like `bodyParser`, `compression`, etc.

```
debug> express
ReferenceError: express is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:44:17)
    at Interface.controlEval (_debugger.js:952:21)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:412:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
```

Can someone please explain why these variables are not defined even after I used `require()`? `server.js` runs fine when I just execute it by `node server.js`. So I don't know why the debugger says some variables that are definitely used are not defined.

Answer (score -1):

You need to go through node require method.

There are some package you require just for adding is"globals"

And most packages you need to require in to variables. IE:

```
var express = require("express");
```

Comment: i have already gone through `var express = requires("express")` at the point I inspected variable `express`. Even after I successfully connected mongodb to this server, variable `mongoose` was undefined.